# asp mvc session loss when redirected to another web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-timeout

I am trying to read the "session" value in my domain, and I am saving the last visited product id in session. I then take the user to pay online using another "REST" api of another website, but when returning from the api website, my session value gets lost in the browser.

These are my Controller's ActionResults:

**Product Details**

```
public ActionResult ProductDetails(int id)
{


Session["LastVisitProductID"] = id;

  return View();

}
```

**Pay Details Form**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PaymentDetailsForm()
{

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.payexample.com/api/pay_online");
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paymentform);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();



// etc... does request and response, if response is successful payment then 
   return url to : SuccessPage

  return View();

}
```

**Success Page**

```
public ActionResult SuccessPage()
{

 int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastVisitProductID"]);

 // Here is the problem session value is 0 or null              

     if (id == 0 || id == null)
     {

                        return RedirectToAction("SomeErrorPage");
     }
return View();


}
```

I wish to know what it is that I am doing wrong, how can I persist "session" in my site even when redirected to another site.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why are you storing data this type of information in the session? Why don't you store it in a strongly typed model?

Comment: @Jamie  Rees, yes i can store the id in db and retrieve
 but is there a solution for session issue ?

Comment: Cookies are your friend here.